# How to switch accounts via VS Code Azure Account Extension

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code

I've signed into one of my Azure accounts with Azure Account Extension via VS Code.  I didn't find any button to sign out or switch accounts.  How do I sign out or switch accounts?

Comment: It's in the documentation https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azure-account

Comment: Before I posted this question,  I've read this document. But I don't understand how to use the command. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

There is no button that you can find to sign in or sign out in VS Code with  Azure Account Extension. The extension works with commands from Command Palette.

[image]

In VS Code press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to see the command palette and write the symbol `>`, after that you can see any command you need including the `sign out` command to work with this extension.

Comment: Yeah just press `Ctrl+Shift+p` and the symbol `>` and then you can see most commands. VS Code is great.

Comment: Nice mate!
This was really helpful!!

Comment: After I open the psh terminal, I used the below 

Install-Module Az -RequiredVersion 9.0.1 -Scope CurrentUser -Force -AllowClobber 
Install-Module Az
Import-Module Az
Connect-Azaccount

Comment: I guess a "sign out" button would make things too easy

Answer (score 40):

Use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to bring up VS Code command palette

In the command palette prompt that appears type:

```
Azure: Sign Out
```

Answer (score 15):

The shortest way to achieve this in vscode is by pressing `F1` to show the command pallet and then type `azso` (**Az**ure **S**ign **O**ut), first letter of each word, and press enter.

Note that this "first letter of each word" also works with other commands, very handy if you're a keyboard/shortcut person.

Answer (score 14):

If anyone still facing this problem:

- Click on `Accounts` Icon in the bottom left of VS Code
- You will see the account sign in with Microsoft, Click on that and click sign out
- Then you can sign in with another account.

[image: Switch account]

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to sign out from your azure account within `Visual Studio Code`

the first one is to open the command palette code using those hot keys:

in Windows/MacOS: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, then type `azure sign out`

[image: azure sign out]

⚠ Sometimes this method doesn't work, but there is an alternative way to do it, by clicking on the

<kbd>웃</kbd> `User Icon` then <kbd>Sign Out</kbd> down on the left side as you can see from this picture:

[image: azure sign out vscode]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that I resolved as follows. There may be better ways of doing it. I just tried this work around to see if it works - and it did for me:

1. Use [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/) to sign in via the `PowerShell` (I have latest version 7.3) using
   `PS ...> az login`
2. In the same PowerShell Window, set your desired subscription as follows:

   `PS ...> az account set --subscription 'Your subscription name or Id'`
3. In `VSCode`, in any of the Azure task window, place your mouse over the task window (e.g. Static Web Apps window) label and click on the refresh icon as shown below. This will show list of all your subscriptions (I have two subscriptions shown below). Select your desired subscription.

[image]