# Azure resources not showing up in VS Code Extension

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Recently, something has change with the Azure resources view in the VS Code extension.

I have 3 accounts I typically sign in with:

1. Personal
2. My Company
3. My customer

As recently as the April timeframe, I was able to use the extension to deploy logic apps into my customer's Azure tenant.  Now whenever I sign in to them, I see nothing in the extension, in fact it behaves as if I've not signed in at all.  But my other two accounts work as expected.

[No Resources in customer account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRCo9.png)

[My Company account with resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8xbH.png)

I have signed in/out multiple times.  I have uninstalled/reinstalled the extension(s).  This is happening on both my Windows 11 and Mac machines.

I'm down to beleiving that this may be some corporate restriction/policy implemented by my customer's IT, as they are trying to reorganize and restructure their Azure environments.  And yes, I still have access overall, because I can log into the portal see the resources just fine.

Would anyone know of such a setting, and what it might be?  Or know anything else to try?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Despite wrestling with this for over an hour yesterday, it appears to have resolved itself, or my one last try of starting with a rebooted machine, signing in to the portal first, THEN signing in with the extension seems to have got it back up and running....

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sign out of Azure in VS Code using this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53707442/79558

Then I signed into portal.azure.com, then signed back into VS Code.

I'm wondering if it had something to do with my org requiring multi factor authn more often for access to portal.azure.com.